# If check box is selected add style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a fill color if check box is checked and then remove color when the box is unchecked. Need to be able to check multiple check boxes at once.

So far I'm only able to add the color in path-> style, but not able to remove it when box is unchecked.

so far this is what i have:

```
<form id="mapform" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue"> blue<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green"> green<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="yellow" > yellow<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red" > red<br>
</form> 

<a class="color" xlink:href="#"> 
   <path color="blue" style="enable-background:accumulate;color:#000000;" d="m1847.9,1886.3,24.914-1.9938,2.9897,46.856-25.911,0-8.969-28.912z" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</a>

<a class="color" xlink:href="#"> 
   <path color="green" style="enable-background:accumulate;color:#000000;" d="m1847.9,1886.3,24.914-1.9938,2.9897,46.856-25.911,0-8.969-28.912z" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</a>

<a class="color" xlink:href="#"> 
   <path color="yellow" style="enable-background:accumulate;color:#000000;" d="m1847.9,1886.3,24.914-1.9938,2.9897,46.856-25.911,0-8.969-28.912z" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</a>

<a class="color" xlink:href="#"> 
   <path color="red" style="enable-background:accumulate;color:#000000;" d="m1847.9,1886.3,24.914-1.9938,2.9897,46.856-25.911,0-8.969-28.912z" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mapform input").change(function(){   

        var checkedColor = $("#mapform input:checked").val();   
        $("path[color*="+ checkedColor +"]").css("fill","#008fff");
        $("path[color!="+checkedColor+"]").css("fill","#595a5c"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Don't `<path>` elements belong inside `<svg>` elements?

Comment: yes that's where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is now when the checkbox is unchecked `checkedColor` won't have any value, the selector won't match it. Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mapform input").change(function(){   
        var checkedColor = $(this).val();
        var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
        if(checked)
        {
            $("path[color="+ checkedColor +"]").css("fill","#008fff");
        }
        else
        {
            $("path[color="+checkedColor+"]").css("fill","#595a5c");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is it possible to reverse the function,  lets say I click on the a.color and the check box has checked applied to it?

Answer (score 2):

*Adding to @amura.cxgs answer and answering your follow up question*

Yes it's possible to have "the reverse" behaviour.
You need to hookup the `click` event of the anchor.

```js
$('#mapform input').change(function() {
  var checkedColor = $(this).val();
  var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  $('path[color*=' + checkedColor + ']').css('fill', checked ? checkedColor : '#595a5c');
});

$('a.color').on('click', function() {
  var checkedColor = $('path', this).attr('color');
  var checked = $('#mapform input[value*="' + checkedColor + '"]').prop('checked');
  $('#mapform input[value*="' + checkedColor + '"]').prop('checked', !checked);
  $('path[color*=' + checkedColor + ']').css('fill', !checked ? checkedColor : '#595a5c');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mapform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue" />blue
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green" />green
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="yellow" />yellow
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red" />red
  <br />
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a class="color" xlink:href="#">
    <path color="blue" d="M0 0 H 10 V 10 H -10 Z" />
  </a>
  <a class="color" xlink:href="#">
    <path color="green" d="M0 30 H 10 V 20 H -20 Z" />
  </a>
  <a class="color" xlink:href="#">
    <path color="yellow" d="M0 50 H 10 V 40 H -40 Z" />
  </a>
  <a class="color" xlink:href="#">
    <path color="red" d="M0 70 H 10 V 60 H -60 Z" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks, it almost works, when i click on path the color does not stay selected in path

Comment: how do i make the color default when not selected?